# How to bind a System.Windows.Path to ContentPresenter?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a class which has a properties called MyIcon from type System.Windows.Path. Now I want to display the data and I want to draw the path to a ContentPresenter within a DataTemplate.

But

```
<ContentPresenter Content={Binding MyIcon}/>
```

doesn't work. I recieve an XAML exception.
So how can I bind my path to a ContentPresenter or something like this to display it within a DataTemplate?

Thanks.

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410651/applying-style-to-path-inside-contentpresenter-basedon-not-working

Comment: Value does not fall within the expected range.